# "dynamic" return type present when using TLBIMP to generate interop assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dynamic, com-interop, tlbimp

I have a COM control that has a **MyCOMCtl** class having **Data** property which is available as **get_Data** in the generated COM Interop assembly. Two different interop assemblies are generated for this COM control:

1. By adding the COM control in VS2010, an interop (and Ax...) is automatically generated.
2. Using TLBIMP v4 Tool from VS2010 command prompt.

The problem is that when the interop assembly is generated using TLBIMP then the get_Data becomes:

```
dynamic MyCOMCtl::get_Data(...)
```

but when its auto-generated by VS2010 then it becomes:

```
object MyCOMCtl::get_Data(...)
```

My code needs the second one that returns an *object*. The VS2010 project targets *.NET Framwork 4 Client Profile* and TLBIMP version is 4.0.30319.1.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to **correct** this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are mixing things up. `tlbimp` should not create dynamic types for [backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1187197/1254352) reasons.

However, Visual Studio generates dynamic types when using [NoPIA](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2010/01/24/the-pain-of-deploying-primary-interop-assemblies.aspx). NoPIA means, that you do not have to ship an primary interop assembly together with your control. Also the types are not generated by `tlbimp` any longer. Instead they are directly created within the assembly that imports the type library. You can (and imho should) disable this setting by right-clicking the COM reference in Visual Studio, choosing the "Properties" menu and setting the "Embed interop types" property to false. You will see, that the Visual Studio generated reference also creates an `object` return type.

However, this is not completely correct yet. If you are generating an (primary) interop library for your control using tlbimp, you should also reference it! Do not add a COM reference to your project. Instead browse for the tlbimp-generated interop library and add this one.